# Multi threaded BIOS

Tags: multithreading, bios, uefi

I would like to know why the BIOS is single-threaded even we have 4 cores/8 cores. Latest UEFI technology allows GUI utilities. Is there any specific reason for not implementing Multi-threaded BIOS.

Comment: Please edit your post and provide more background on the processor and architecture more.

Comment: I'm confused why you would even need a multithreaded BIOS.

Comment: its about Intel architectures only. older BIOS utilities may be blue screen apps like ncurses application. but latest UEFI supports animated stuffs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is: Diminishing Returns

On most PCs, the boot sequence of BIOS/UEFI only takes ~5 seconds to work (Not counting HDD spinup latency).  To most people, that is fast enough.  (If you want faster, put your PC to sleep instead of turning it off.)

Keep in mind that many of the tasks done in the BIOS cannot be parallelized.  The memory controller has to be initialized first.  The PCI/PCIe busses must be enumerated before you can check any of the subsequent devices (USB, SATA, Video, etc).  You can't boot until you disks have spun up.

There **are** a few initialization items that are time-consuming, and could be done in parallel.

- IDE/SATA - Usually takes a while due to mechanical disk latencies.
- USB - Some USB devices need 100s of msec after power is applied to come to life.
- Video (any any other third-party BIOS extensions) - It takes a while to communicate with the displays and sync up.

Those tasks could be done in parallel, which might speed up your PC's boot time.  Keep in mind that to get there, you need to write a kernel and task scheduler.  In legacy BIOS (pure x86 assembler), this would not be pretty.  In UEFI (which is mostly C source), this is a little more feasible.  However, it still requires a non-trivial engineering effort for a minor gain (maybe 1-2 second of boot time.)

Phoenix has tried to introduce a multi-threaded BIOS initialization before.  As far as I know, it never took off.

Comment: Thanks. Lets leave BIOS. we talk about diagnosis applications which runs before OS boot.

Comment: Pre-boot UEFI Applications are a niche product (the average user will never touch it).  Nothing precludes you developing your own UEFI app with its own task scheduler.  The task scheduler would be part of your app, not part of the framework.

Comment: So what the average users don't touch should not be made efficient and fast. And these companies say they're excited about _technology_...

Answer (score 4):

Because there is no need. The BIOS does not do heavy computations. It does some coordination and then exits (forever).

Comment: Yes. But with the introduction of UEFI which allows animated BIOS utility, we may in need of Multi-threading in BIOS.

Answer (score 2):

**UEFI** does not describe any multiprocessing functionality. However, the **PI** specification [(also produced by the UEFI Forum)](http://uefi.org/specifications/) does, and [**EDK2**](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2) provides the `EFI_MP_SERVICES_PROTOCOL` (currently for IA32/X64 only).

It is not exactly pthreads, but it does let you schedule tasks to run on *Application Processors* while the *Bootstrap Processor* keeps providing the single-threaded UEFI instance.

The interface for DXE phase is described in Volume 3 of the v1.5 PI specification, section *MP Services Protocol* (13.4).

Functionality available during PEI are described by Volume 2, *EFI MP Services PPI* (8.3.9).